# Python multiprocessing runs forever

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I ran https://gist.github.com/amitsaha/2036026 which calculates pi with a monte carlo method and all of my processors. I changed the number of points to 10,000 to make sure it should finish near-instantly. However, the program never terminates. My cpu monitor shows all cores running at ~half load indefinitely. I have the same trouble with many other examples for which other users report success. I'm on win 7 x64, Python 2.7.7, using Pyscripter for my IDE. Closing Pyscripter ends the cpu usage, but I can't end them with the stop button. ???

Answer (score 4):

Seems that this is a bug with PyScripter + `multiprocessing` module on Windows:

https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/issues/detail?id=722

Try running the code without pyscripter (i.e. from the command prompt), on my machine it finishes in less than a second.